# Issue multithreading `terraform init` executable via subprocess module in Python

Tags: python, terraform, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am experiencing an issue when multithreading the `terraform init` command on a set of subdirectories within Python. The output of the `terraform init` subprocess is showing the expected results, ie. the stdout from the `terraform init` executable, but the `ThreadPoolExecutable` is returning as completed before the executable finishes writing the `.terraform` file to the subdirectory. For now I have generated a workaround that just continually executes the same command until the file is present, but seeing as I want to multithread `terraform apply --auto-approve` next, this workaround won't work. Is this an issue with the underlying executable or should I be using another module like `asyncio` or `multiprocessing`? Any and all help is much appreciated.

```
class InitializeDirectory():

    def __init__(self):
        self.base_path = Path(__file__).parent

    def init_dir(self, event):
        print(event)
        while len(os.listdir(event)) == 1:
            try:
                init: List[str] = ['terraform', 'init']
                os.chdir(event)
                result = subprocess.run(init, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

def main(path):
    
    subdirs = gather_subdirectories(path)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        todo = []
        for _dir in subdirs:
            initializer = InitializeDirectory()
            future = executor.submit(initializer.init_dir, _dir)
            todo.append(future)
        results = []
        for future in as_completed(todo):
            res = future.result()
            results.append(res)
            print(len(results))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(subdir_path)
```

Comment: Are you seeing the command executions returning immediately, or are they taking some significant amount of time and yet returning before each command has completed?  Have you tried to reproduce this issue outside of Python?  I'd try to do that, as I don't see any reason why you'd get a different behavior than if you ran these commands simultaneously via some other mechanism. For example, you could run a shell script that runs these "terraform init" commands as background processes (via `&`).

Comment: They are returning asynchronously after a small amount of time - about the time it takes for `terraform init` to run via command line execution. I haven't yet tried invoking a shell script to invoke the executable, but I can certainly try that. The motivation behind it being a Python subprocess call is to keep the application driver succinct, as the infrastructure build is a part of the application itself.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused.  So it sound like you're saying that Python might be running `terraform init` correctly, since it acts the same way as if you run it at the command line. But after the command runs, the `.terraform` file isn't there until some time later.  Is that right?  Does the same thing happen when you run the command from the command line?  For example, if you run `terraform init && ls -l .terraform`, does that fail because the file isn't there right after `terraform` returns?  It sounds like something more is going on here than meets the eye.

Comment: Ah, Sorry for the confusion! Yeah, so the `terraform init` executable seems to be running correctly, or at least the stdout from the executable is what it should be, but the `.terraform` file is oftentimes not created in any given set of the subdirectories I am calling `terraform init` on. Sometimes 4/5 subdirectories will correctly have the `.terraform` file after the script runs, but occasionally only 2/5 will. I haven't ever experienced this behavior when running `terraform init` manually, so I think it may be something in my invocation of the Thread Pool?Or maybe I should just try asyncio?

Comment: A few comments about your code.  First off, I wouldn't run "terraform init" multiple times because you don't get the expected output the first time.  Doing so can only lead to new problems.  You need to figure out why the command is failing the first time, or why it is succeeding but your code is failing to recognize that.   Second, I would suggest that instead of testing the length of a directory listing, you check for the existence of the specific file you're expecting to have show up, with `os.path.exists()`.

Comment: I only just saw your last comment.  I very much doubt that if `terraform init` is running at all, it's doing the wrong thing because it is a Python program that is running it.  I'm an old fart that has been doing this for a long time, and I can't think of any reason why Python would be to blame so long as the execution of the command is occurring and completing.  I think it's more likely that you haven't seen this behavior because your Python code is doing something logically different than you've ever done at the command line, even though each individual execution is technically correct.

Comment: ...not that I can see from your code why this would occur, but one explanation would be that you are running `terraform init` twice in the same directory.  I'm thinking it has to be something like that.  I see that you're logging the path to each directory, so you likely can see that that isn't happening.  I'm just grasping at straws here.  I'll say again that the retry loop can't, IMO, be helping. I'd take that out. But I guess that loop hasn't been there all along, so that isn't part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! Yeah, the loop is the workaround that ensures the `.terraform` file is created, otherwise the issue occurs where the the executable is run, but the output directory isn't generated within the respective subdirectory. I agree that it probably isn't an issue with Python executing `terraform init` properly, or with the underlying executable, but rather an issue with how my threads are being handled. I will continue digging into asyncio and see if that handles the situation better.